# Create a view from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table1 consists of the following columns:-

```
BuyerID
SellerID
SupplierID
Description
```

Table2 consists of the following columns which contains user data:-

```
ID
Name
UserName
Account
WorkEmail
```

And I would like to create a view which consists of all the columns from Table1 as below:-

```
BuyerName 
SellerName 
SupplierName 
Description
```

All the names are based on the id which can be found in Table2.
How to create a view based on above requirements in SQL Server ?

Comment: Do do have problem with `Create a View` or `above requirements`?

Answer (score 0):

I think all you needed to do is figure out the SQL Query which would serve your purpose. Creating view is just an additional statement above the SELECT query.

This query would do -

```
CREATE VIEW Info AS
SELECT BuyerInfo.Name AS BuyerName,
SellerInfo.Name AS SellerName,
SupplierInfo.Name AS SupplierName,
T1.Description AS Description
FROM Table1 T1 JOIN Table2 BuyerInfo
ON T1.BuyerID = BuyerInfo.ID
JOIN Table2 SellerInfo
ON T1.SellerID = SellerInfo.ID
JOIN Table2 SupplierInfo
ON T1.SupplierID = SupplierInfo.ID;
```

You can run this query to see the result -

```
SELECT * FROM Info;
```